# Dividing Courses Into Groups so that Courses Don't Clash

Tags: algorithms

So our university has this system for preparing the schedule of lectures every semester: They offer a certain set of courses every semester, they ask the students to pre-register for their preferred set of courses to know about their choices, and then divide the courses into 8 groups. Each group has a corresponding time slot in the weekly lecture schedule. Now a student cannot take two courses from the same group because they are taught in the same time slot. The course groups are to be made so that the number of such clashes is minimum.

I tried to formulate this mathematically: Let $M$ be the set of courses, say with cardinality $m$, $S$ the set of students, with cardinality $s$. $\forall j \in S$, we have $M_j \subset M$, the set of the courses the student has pre-registered for. Now, we have to divide the set $M$ into $n$ (=8 here) distinct classes $C_1,..., C_n$. A **Clash** is defined by a pair (not ordered) $(x,y)$ so that $\exists C_i$ with $i\in {1,...,n}$ and $j\in S$ such that $x,y\in C_i \cap M_j$. We are looking for an algorithm for finding $C_i$'s for given $S$, $M$ and $M_j$'s that minimize the total number of clashes.

Does such an algorithm exist? Will the minimum-clash-group-division be unique?

Comment: This sounds like a typical scheduling problem, which can be solved with CP-SAT restrictions with a library like [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling) from Google which has some optimization functions, and which has a little guide to use it for nurse scheduling. I've used it for other scheduling purposes similar to yours. I assume like any scheduling-like problem, it's NP-complete, so just translating it to an already known problem will be enough to find an algorithm.